# How to delete two rows before and two rows after minimum value of column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to delete two rows before and two rows after minimum of column value , is there efficient way to do this in pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,0.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]})

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,0.5,2,2,2,2,2]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s=df.A.idxmin()
df=df.drop(set(range(s-2,s+3))-{s})
      A
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
5   0.5
8   2.0
9   2.0
10  2.0
11  2.0
12  2.0
```

Comment: AWESOME AND PYTHONIC !

Comment: @ good , here is one problem , if sometime in real data before minimum have only 1 rows how to avoid from index not found error ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S   , KeyError: '[28499 28500 28501 ... 29718 29719 29720] not found in axis'

Comment: @Edward do df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) first

Comment: @YOBEN_S I did this , but the reason is : sometime number of rows after minimum are less than 2 or number of rows before minimum are less than 2 , so because not enough rows so thats why through error,  in solution need to add if after or before minimum rows are not 2 then use just available rows

Answer (score -1):

Based on @YOBEN_S's answer, but dropping only existing indexes:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,0.5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]})

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,0.5,2,2,2,2,2]})
min_idx=df.A.idxmin()
s1 = set(range(s-2,s+3))
s2 = set(df.index.tolist())
s1 = s1.intersection(s2)

df=df.drop(set(s1-{min_idx})
```

Comment: Would be interested to know why the dowvote, as I'm quite new in answering here, so I'm interested in improving.